# GRASS Geoprocessing in Python Script

Tags: python, geoprocessing, grass-gis, open-source-gis, python-2.6

I´m trying to get some GRASS geoprocessig tools running in a python script outside GRASS.
I´m able to import grass.script, but I´m not able to get the tools running yet. Does anybody know what I´m doing wrong?

```
import os, sys
import subprocess as subp

gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE'] = "C:/GRASS GIS 7"
gisdbase = os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'])
location = "Martin"
mapset   = "PERMANENT"

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.environ['GISBASE'], "etc", "python"))

import grass.script as grass
import grass.script.setup as gsetup

gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdbase, location, mapset)
grass.run_command("v.hull", input="D:\Python_Test\1.shp", output="D:\Python_Test\5.shp")
```

It runs up till `grass.run_command`, but as a result I only get `-1073741515` in pythonwin. Once I get this running, I want to combine ArcPy and GRASS tools in one script. Could it have to do something with the fact that I´m using the ArcGIS Python installation (2.6)?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I´m still a python beginner with not too much programming experience.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a shapefile directly. You must first import it as a Grass layer in your mapset "Martin". A name beginning with a number (1.shp) is not allowed in Grass
Also, in order to use GRASS functionality via Python from outside, some environment variables have to be set (see [GRASS and Python](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python)):

after that you can use grass.script in the Python Shell:

```
import grass.script as grass
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
gisbase = os.environ['GISBASE']
gisdb="...your grassdata folder"
location="Martin"
mapset="PERMANENT"
gsetup.init(gisbase, gisdb, location, mymapset)
grass.run_command("v.hull", input="layer", output="layer2")
or
grass.parse_command(""v.hull", input="layer", output="layer2")

....
```

see [GRASS Python Scripting Library](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_Python_Scripting_Library) or [Python Scripts For GRASS GIS](http://code.google.com/p/postgis-grass-r-py/wiki/0003_01_PythonForGrassGis)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunally it´still not working. I still get the same error on: grass.run_command('v.in.ogr', dsn="D:/Python_Test/a.shp", layer="a", output="a") 
grass.run_command('v.hull', input="a", output="b")
grass.run_command('v.out.ogr', input="b", dsn="D:/Python_Test/b.shp", format="ESRI_Shapefile"). I guess it has to do with the different the Python versions. ArcGIS 10.0 still uses 2.6 while GRASS uses 2.7

Comment: After using ArcPy and GRASS both with Python 2.7 it´s actually workig now. I´m accepting this answer because the points mentioned are important to keep in mind.

Comment: Just FYI, in GRASS GIS 7 there is now also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Python/pygrass