# Difference between python IDLE and eclipse on accessing GRASS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, python-2.7, windows-8, eclipse

I have seen these posts:[GRASS and Python](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python), [Using Eclipse to develop GRASS Python programs](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Using_Eclipse_to_develop_GRASS_Python_programs).

I used to use python IDLE to control GRASS, but I can't make python and GRASS connected, as I described in this post:[Problem with python script to control GRASS GIS from outside - How to import grass.script under Win 8.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89452/problem-with-python-script-to-control-grass-gis-from-outside-how-to-import-gra)

So now I am thinking of using eclipse to control GRASS, trying to avoid problems I faced as I used python IDLE. But I don't know whether I will get the same problem after I use eclipse, and I can't tell the difference between using python IDLE alone and using eclipse.

I am working with GRASS 6.4.3 and python 2.7.6 under WIN 8.1.

Can you help me to make decision and furthermore, to solve the connecting problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be a difference in GRASS and Python working together using either IDLE or Eclipse. You have to connect your Python installation to your GRASS. I think the easiest option is using a .pth file (check out my answer to your other post at [Problem with python script to control GRASS GIS from outside - How to import grass.script under Win 8.1?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89452))

I am using [Pyscripter](https://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) for writing Python scripts and I am pretty happy with it.