# Entry point not found Error initiating GRASS GIS from Python

Tags: grass-gis, python-2.7, grass-7.0, grass.script

I cannot run any GRASS tools from within Python 2.7.15. While the GRASS environment, grass.script etc. are loading correctly and I can run basic checks like

```
gscript.read_command('g.gisenv')
gscript.read_command('g.mapset', flags='p')
```

but receiving this error (screenshot) every time I tried to run tools like

```
gscript.read_command('g.proj', flags='p')
gscript.read_command('g.region', flags='p')
```

[image]

Everything was running smoothly before. If you want to check the startup script that I'm using, please see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284601/cannot-run-some-grass-commands-in-python-using-grass-script)). Not duplicating here as already posted earlier. This problem started after I fresh-installed Anaconda 2 with Python 2.7.15 to fix some broken Python libraries.

Already tried fresh installing GRASS 7.4, restarting the machine after each install and uninstall. But not fixing this issue. Need to run the previously working scripts desperately. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was solved by uninstalling xerces-c package and all its dependencies (including GDAL) using conda command line, restarting the machine and reinstalling the xerces-c package with the dependencies.

Absolute pain, no doubt!!