# How to use GRASS GIS in Python standalone?

Tags: python, grass-gis

I'm trying to use GRASS module in a Python Skript. I already checked this:
[Is it possible to use GRASS GIS in Python stand alone scripts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73639/is-it-possible-to-use-grass-gis-in-python-stand-alone-scripts)
and this [Using Python script to control GRASS GIS from outside?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89452/using-python-script-to-control-grass-gis-from-outside)
but it doesn't help with my problem.
I did `pip install grass-session` which worked well. My script is just:
`import grass_session` and when I run it I get the error `RuntimeError: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script: 'grass', set the right one using the GRASSBIN environm. variable`.

First I tried `GRASSBIN="$path\\to\\software\\grass\\grass78 python grass.py"` as suggested in
https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly in the block **Python: GRASS GIS 7 with an external library: grass-session** but I still got the same error.

After checking http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASSBIN-environment-variable-td5413301.html I solved this error adding the following line before the import line: `os.environ['GRASSBIN']=r"path\to\software\grass\grass78"`, although I feel this only should be necessary if my grass version is different from 7.8.

Now when I run these two lines first I'm happy to see that I don't get the error again but after a while I notice that nothing happens. It keeps running without any exit code unless I stop the script manually. I would expect the script to import the module and finish with exit code 0.

I have grass gis 7.8.2. installed with QGIS and Python 3.7 and working on Windows 10 Pro 64 bit.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already started GRASS interactively, and created a LOCATION/MAPSET, then try the full code example:[from the wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_with_existing_location).

If you do not yet have your GRASS DB setup, and you want to try constructing a temporary location using python, then the next [wiki section](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Working_with_GRASS_without_starting_it_explicitly#Python:_GRASS_GIS_7_without_existing_location_using_metadata_only) gives a working example.

Please try those complete examples, then post back if something does not work.

*Edited:*

You should **not** have to do any `pip install grass`. In the setup script are the lines:

```
# Set GISBASE environment variable
os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase
# define GRASS-Python environment
gpydir = os.path.join(gisbase, "etc", "python")
sys.path.append(gpydir)
```

If you have GRASS installed, that should take care of finding the GRASS python module `grass.script`. Can you double check that you are getting the paths correct, etc.??

Comment: Hi Micha, sorry for the delay, I had holiday. I've tried the second option because it works better for me but I noticed that the code is written in python 2 and I had to addapt some parts to python 3. Now the code was able to create a new location but I get the error:
`import grass.script as grass`
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'grass.script'; 'grass' is not a package`

Comment: After doing pip install grass, setting the grassbin env manually with os.environ['GRASSBIN'] = r"path" and importing grass_session before the import grass.script as grass line, it trhrows the next error at line `grass.message('--- GRASS GIS 7: Current GRASS GIS 7 environment:')` The error is very long and I can only copy the last part: `grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None g.gisenv -n ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code 3221225781. See errors in the (error) output.`

Comment: If you have GRASS installed, you should **not** do `pip install grass`. See edits above.

Comment: I think my paths are corerct 
gisbase: D:\path\to\QGIS_3.10\apps\grass\grass78
gpydir: D:\path\to\QGIS_3.10\apps\grass\grass78\etc\python
with these paths I get the error no module named 'grass.script'; 'grass' is not a package

Comment: I get the other error `grass.exceptions.CalledModuleError: Module run None g.gisenv -n ended with error Process ended with non-zero return code 3221225781. See errors in the (error) output.` by changing 'etc' to 'Python' in the gpydir path, which I did just for trying and I was surprised to see that that way I avoid the import error, but to be honest I'm not sure why

Comment: Do you actually use "nVIZ" - https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/wxGUI.nviz.html ?

Answer (score 0):

Here an updated script which uses the [grass-session](https://github.com/zarch/grass-session) pip package. It shows some GRASS GIS variables and runs a small statistical computation on a LAZ file ([simple.laz](https://github.com/OSGeo/grass/raw/main/docker/testdata/simple.laz)) with [r.in.pdal](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.in.pdal.html). The `grassdata` directory needs to exist.

Installation:

```
pip install grass-session
```

Python script (please adapt the paths to `grassdata` and `simple.laz` to your local settings as well as the EPSG code) below, you can set the shell variable `GRASSBIN` to the name of your GRASS GIS startup script (e.g., `grass82`, so `export GRASSBIN=grass82`) before running the Python session:

```
from grass_session import Session
import grass.script as gs

# hint: do not use ~ as an alias for HOME
with Session(
    # run in PERMANENT mapset after creation of location "test"
    gisdb="/path/to/grassdata/",
    location="test",
    create_opts="EPSG:4326",
):
    print("grass-session: tests for PROJ, GDAL, PDAL, GRASS GIS")
    print(gs.parse_command("g.gisenv", flags="s"))

    # simple test: just scan the LAZ file
    gs.run_command(
        "r.in.pdal",
        input="/path/to/simple.laz",
        output="count_1",
        method="n",
        flags="g",
        resolution=1,
        overwrite=True,
    )
```

Certainly one can store the script in a file and execute it with `python` (should be Python >= v3.6).