# Python library for geometrical calculations using with GRASS GIS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, geometry

I have to do some geometrical calculations in 2D(point, lines, line segments and intersection points) in Python, and then use it in GRASS GIS. What is the best library to use for it? I'm trying with SymPy, but I'm not sure is that good choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy is inappropriate here (or very difficult to use). For geometrical calculations in 2D, the best solution is [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html).

But don't forget that  GRASS GIS 6.4.x has the module grass.script (look at [GRASS Geoprocessing in Python Script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49954/2581)) and GRASS GIS 7.x, the new module [pygrass](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/libpython/).

You can also use the general Python modules [GDAL/OGR (osgeo)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.11.1) or [Fiona](http://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html) to open and save the GRASS vector files.

After, it is possible to mix all as in  [GRASS and the Python geospatial modules (Shapely, PySAL,...)](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GRASS-and-the-Python-geospatial-modules-Shapely-PySAL-td4985075.html)

Comment: Thank You! I hope it's easy to rewrite my code with Shapely.