# Use Function V.clean of the grass tool in a Python script

Tags: python, pyqgis, grass.script

I need to integrate V.clean functionality of Grass in a script python. this functionnality is accessible in Qgis (Processing->tools).
I found that I should use Grass API but I don't know the code syntax, Please give me examples of use of the Grass API functionalities in a Python script, especially the v.clean function

Comment: When you load the `v.clean` function in QGIS, you should see 3 tabs: "Parameters", "Log", "Help". Click "Help" and scroll near the bottom and find the heading 'EXAMPLES'. Here you can see how the syntax should be used.

Comment: there 'is no script in the help page, we have just description of the different functionnalities

Comment: In that case, check these posts: [GRASS Geoprocessing in Python Script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49906/grass-geoprocessing-in-python-script) and [Is it possible to use GRASS GIS in Python stand alone scripts?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73639/is-it-possible-to-use-grass-gis-in-python-stand-alone-scripts)